# Modx не позволяет создавать php файлы

Tags: php, modx

Привет!
Пытаюсь как администратор создать php файл в админке. При попытке сохранить новый файл вижу "Расширение php не допускается". Какая настройка и где за это отвечает? На другом сайте на modx со стандартными настройками и правами на папку как здесь -
 я могу создавать php.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию в целях безопасности php файлы не разрешены к загрузке и созданию. Если все же это необходимо, нужно добавить php в список разрешенных файлов:

Системные настройки > Файловая система > Разрешённые к загрузке файлы (upload_files).

Comment: Про эту опцию я прекрасно помню. Однако тогда я по сути разрешу пользователям грузить php скрипты на мой сайт и разумеется их потом спокойно запускать на исполнение. Этого, разумеется, я хочу избежать.    У меня есть несколько сайтов, где возможность создавать файлы php в админке присутствует сразу же. И я так и не понял, от чего это зависит. Неужели от хостинга? что-то как-то обескураживает...
И кстати, я не уверен, что опция "upload_files" разрешает создавать файлы. Она вроде делает только то, что собственно отражено в ее названии - позволяет ЗАГРУЖАТЬ файлы, но не создавать

Comment: Загрузка и создание это одно и тоже - работа с файловой системой. Разрешение и запрет исходит именно из этого. Вы задали вопрос - получили ответ.

Comment: То, что создание и загрузка файлов это работа с файловой системой это и так понятно. Однако тот же modx разделяет правами отдельно создание и отдельно загрузку. 
А фразы в духе "Вы задали вопрос - получили ответ" -  констатация факта, не имеющая необходимости.
Я ж и веду к тому, что на многих других сайтах у меня по умолчанию администратор может создавать файлы php, здесь же нет и именно поэтому я и интересуюсь, что и где я мог настроить не так.